# How do companies/employers fill roles when they have unrealistic or below-market salary expectations?

Tags: interviewing, salary, job-offer, recruitment, negotiation

I've had a couple of interesting experiences lately, and it has me wondering, how do companies fill positions when they have below-market compensation budgets?

1. I had a recruiter reach out to me about a role with a company. She said that they were going to finalize everything in the next couple days, and she would send me the job description (I've worked with her once before.) A few days later, she said that the company had found their own candidate. However, a couple days after that, HR reaches out to me from that company via LinkedIn and asks if I am interested. I talk with them, and I find out that their compensation budget is a little below market given the amount of experience that they want, so I pass. A few months later, I get another recruiter from a different firm asking if I am interested in the role. It looks like they weren't able to fill it in 4 months.
2. A recruiter reaches out to me about a role. I agree to send the company my resume. 3 months later, they ask me for an interview. I ask the recruiter why it took so long to fill the position. It turns out, they had identified two other candidates in the past 3 months, but they both quit either shortly before/after their start date. I go through the interview process and end up getting an offer. Despite having told the recruiter my salary expectations (I had decided other companies in the past over comp.), they come in below by $5,000. I'm a little skeptical because they sound difficult to work for, and they can't keep anyone, so I tell the recruiter to tell them that I want the extra $5k, and they can take-it-or-leave-it. They decided to pass. Later on, I find out that they were finally able to fill the position, 4 months after I interviewed with them, but overall, it took them about 7 months from when they first started looking.
3. Similar to the above, I interviewed with a company through a recruiter. After a few rounds, the recruiter tells me that they have idenitified a stronger candidate for the role.  A few weeks later, I see the company posted a similar postion on LinkedIn with a lower title and a lower experience requirement. It was a smaller company, so I doubt that it was "different" position, but rather the same position. My guess is that they realized that candidates at that level wanted more money than they could pay, and the recruiter's commission (20-30%) was more than they could afford in total (similar to story #1).

I keep hearing about how there is a labor shortage, and companies cannot find workers, but my experience is showing me that most companies are being very unrealistic right now, and they are either waiting for someone who is disgruntled or clueless about market salaries. I have even more stories in the past few months, but I don't want to turn this into a rant or saga. What has your experience been lately, and have you experienced something similar?

Comment: I would argue that the examples given answer your question: 1. They *aren't* actually filling these roles, 2. They leave the role unfilled for months/years at a time until they get someone willing to do the job for that pay, 3. They change the title/experience requirements to better match the salary they're willing to offer.

Comment: Remember, recruiters are 95% spam bots.

Comment: This is meandering and looking for opinions rather object facts. It could be split as: "Q1. How to fill a role when we can only pay a below-market salary?" or "Q2: Why are recruiters ___. (though any answer here is entirely speculation)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I keep hearing about how there is a labor shortage, and companies cannot find workers, but my experience is showing me that most companies are being very unrealistic right now, and they are either waiting for someone who is disgruntled or clueless about market salaries.

As a counter example, we are looking for two very standard developer positions. One frontend web development with Angular, one backend developer with C#. That's not exactly a niche market there. We cannot *find* someone. And I don't mean we talk to people and they decide to go somewhere else. I mean we cannot *find* candidates. We are looking for people in the whole country since the position is fully remote. We don't have interviews.

I would assume it's something about our company, but when I talk to former colleagues in other companies looking for the same profile, they report the same thing. The market is empty. Only very few people are actually looking.

And I get it. My inbox is full of recruiters trying to get me. And they sometimes even offer more money. So well above market. But... I'm happy where I am. I will not take the inconvenience of having a new job, the random chance of the colleagues there being as a good a team as my current one, for what? A few thousand bucks a year more? Maybe that works in other industries, but it doesn't work for developers, most of us are not in it to optimize for money.

I can remember times when a single ad in a paper would bring in 5-10 candidates. Today, you hire a specialized recruiting agency to tell you that they were successful and you have one interview every other month.

There is work to be done, but there also is a cap. This work is only economically sound if you don't pay more than X for the worker, because it will not sell for more than (X + Profit). So developer salaries are high, but they don't skyrocket. Because customer demand is there, but not indiscriminately. They want service A for price B and only if you can deliver it for less than B, you will actually offer it.

So there can be both a labor shortage *and* companies paying what you perceive as below market. I said "perceive", because you need to be able to actually get a job for the market rate for it to be the market rate. If a company cannot sell their product for the price tag you would stamp on it with your salary, it doesn't matter how long they have to look. They will look until they can find someone they can profit of. No point in hiring someone and selling something and not making a buck. They are not welfare organisations.

Answer (score 6):

You're generalising on guesses triggered by a small sample of experiences.

> how do companies fill positions when they have below-market compensation budgets?

Just advertise the positions and wait for applicants. There are people who for various reasons will take these positions. And these positions are not critical ones that need to be filled immediately.

Comment: These aren't the only examples. I think I've had closer to 7 or 8 experiences similar to this (in my area of the country alone mind you). Don't get me wrong there are other companies that have been a lot better (but didn't get an offer from them). Overall, it seems that most of the interviews and open jobs that I am finding are these more "problematic" companies.

Comment: So why do you keep applying for below market jobs? Or perhaps you should rethink your estimate of market value.

Comment: @Kilisi Or more likely he needs to use better recruiters.  Recruiters don't care about getting you the best deal, they care about filling a role to get that commission.  They recruit for these kinds of roles constantly.  Frequently barely caring if its a fit.  I get at least one recruiter a month asking me, with 20 years experience, if I want a contract in the middle of nowhere for entry level pay.  They use a spray and pray methodology.  So you run into these constantly.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've had recruiters contact me and I'm not even in their country. But I don't bother answering let alone applying for jobs and going through any processes.

Comment: @Kilisi, I don't necessarily apply to below-market jobs. Many times, the range salary is not shared, and when I share my salary expectations with the recruiter, and they share it the company, they come back half way through the interview process by asking if I'll take less money.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago, when applying for a job, I would have given them a salary range. Obviously I would apply at more than one place. If you make an offer, it depends on where in my range it is: If it is at the end of the range, I'll sign up immediately. If it is at the lower end, I'll wait for something better. Assuming others do the same, what happens is: Make a good offer, you fill your position immediately. Make a less good offer, it will take a lot longer, and the best people will be gone.

Today, it seems anyone who is any good has no problem at all in finding employment. My old company interviewed someone on Friday, wrote an offer on Monday, and they came too late! Today, if you need someone and the applicant is any good, you hire them. There are some that are no good, that's too bad. There are some with no experience, so you can your chances. But if you want someone good today, if you can find anyone, you need to offer what they want, or they go elsewhere.

PS. Direct answer to your question title: They don't.

Answer (score 0):

This is why companies are open to sending work to other countries. The companies want to pay less, and it is very difficult to get people in the US for the price they want to pay.

Now, the price they want to pay can be unrealistic. It is possible to send work to countries where technical talent costs 1% to 5% of what that talent costs in the US. On a freelance board, I have seen postings where the company has a history of paying far less than US minimum wage for technical talent.

It helps to identify why a company will pay the higher price for talent in their office: They are paying for the service of sitting in meetings face to face with them. They are paying for the extra value that comes when people talk in offices and come up with new ideas that management hadn't thought of. And some are paying for the privilege of bossing other people. When talent is in short supply, the price goes up.

One reason why talent is in shorter supply is because boomers are retiring. The generation after them has fewer people in it.